# Introductory textbook on fourier analysis

Tags: analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis

I'm going to study fourier analysis with Stein & Shakarachi's 'Fourier Analusis'. However, I want another textbook on fourier analysis to use as an auxiliary textbook. I want some books on fourier analysis that have similar things with Stein's, so it can help me studing main textbook(stein).

I'm considering Folland's 'Fourier analysis and its application', but I'm not sure that it can help me studing Stein's.

Can you recommend me a suitable book? For help, I already studied analysis(+multivariable), complex analysis, and some of real analysis.

Comment: Fourier Analysis by Witomski and Gasquet is a nice introduction.

Comment: I would consider Stein's book to be introductory, as it was written with undergraduates in mind and assumes no knowledge of measure theory or the Lebesgue integral. The book is also very well written and easy to understand (in my opinion at least).

Comment: For an especially elementary overview, see [**Who Is Fourier? A Mathematical Adventure**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0964350432). Also worth looking at is [**Fourier Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0521389917) by T. W. Körner. However, I do not know how much either of these might help in studying from Stein/Shakarachi's book.

Comment: it depends on your level, but I bet you'll need much more than 2 books for understanding everything

Comment: @carmichael561  I would like to ask why do you say that Stein & Shakarachi assumes no knowledge of measure theory or Lebesgue integral ? then How can you solve excercise 2(e) p.59 in it without knowing the basis of $L^2[-\pi, \pi]$, and to know the basis of this space you have to know the space first?

Comment: @MathLover: Stein and Shakarchi's Fourier Analysis book is book one of a four-part series, while measure theory and Lebesgue integration is book three.

Comment: @carmichael561   but I understand from what you said in the second comment that you recommend to the one who wrote the question Stein & Shakarachi of Fourier series..... right?

Comment: @carmichael561  anyway thank u for your recommendation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend you a book 'An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis' written by Yitzhak Katznelson. It will be a little simpler to Stein's textbooks.

Comment: I agree that the book by Katznelson would be an excellent text for this purpose.